# How To Customize Authentication And Authorization in ASP.Net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, custom-membershipprovider

How can i modify the default Authentication System in MVC 4 Internet Application template.
I want to use only social login, have a role based system, maintain a user profile with additional information and allow merging of accounts with different providers.

Comment: I have been asking similar questions about membership providers and seems like nobody cares to answer. Do share your findings once you figure it out.